# Laravel broadcasting auth route simply returns "true"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, pusher

I have my pusher key set and initialized within Laravel 5.3. When I test it on my local environment, it works. When I try to run the exact same code on our production environment, I get this error:

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth info required to subscribe to private-App.User.16"}}}
```

I've confirmed the Pusher key is identical on both my local and production.

The WS initializes on both environments the same:

```
wss://ws.pusherapp.com/app/264P9d412196d622od64d?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&flash=false
```

The only difference that I can see, is that when our production server contacts the Laravel "broadcasting/auth" route, it simply receives `true` in the response body.

When my local contacts "broadcasting/auth" it gets this in the response:

```
{auth: "22459d41299d6228d64d:df5d393fe37df0k3832fa5556098307f145d7e483c07974d8e7b2609200483f8"}
```

Within my `BroadcastServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes();

    // Authenticate the user's personal channel.
    Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function (User $user, $user_id) {
        return (int)$user->id === (int)$user_id;
    });
}
```

What could cause the `broadcast/auth` route to return simply `true` instead of the expected auth?

Comment: Shouldn't that be on `route/channels.php` ? [Link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php)

Comment: @AntoniosTsimourtos that is for versions after Laravel 5.3.

Comment: This is basic but I guess it worth asking: are you using `composer.lock` to make sure you have the same deps in both envs?

Comment: I would try to find out which method is handling the `broadcasting/auth` request and then debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check `PusherBroadcaster.php` file, you will see that the response can be "mixed".

I think the documentation is saying about the default broadcast only.

> The channel method accepts two arguments: the name of the channel and
>   a callback which returns true or false indicating whether the user is
>   authorized to listen on the channel.

This is the `validAuthenticationResponse` method inside `PusherBroadcast`.

```
/**
 * Return the valid authentication response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $result
 * @return mixed
 */
public function validAuthenticationResponse($request, $result)
{
    if (Str::startsWith($request->channel_name, 'private')) {
        return $this->decodePusherResponse(
            $this->pusher->socket_auth($request->channel_name, $request->socket_id)
        );
    }

    return $this->decodePusherResponse(
        $this->pusher->presence_auth(
            $request->channel_name, $request->socket_id, $request->user()->getAuthIdentifier(), $result)
    );
}
```

Just to give you another example, this is inside `RedisBroadcast`.

```
if (is_bool($result)) {
    return json_encode($result);
}
```

Short explanation about this "auth request":

`BroadcastManager` instantiate all "available drivers" (Pusher, Redis, Log,etc) , and create the "auth" route (*using BroadcastController + authenticate method*).

When you call "auth", this will happen:

1. Call "broadc.../auth" route.
2. BroadcastManager will instantiate the proper driver (*in your case Pusher*)
3. `PusherBroadcaster` can throw an exception `AccessDeniedHttpException` if the user is not authenticated (the "user session" - Auth::user() is not defined/null) and is trying to access a private (or presence) channel type.
4. If the user is trying to access a `private/presence` channel and the user is authenticated (*Auth::check()*), Laravel will check if the auth. user can access the channel. (Check: `verifyUserCanAccessChannel` method).
5. After that, `validAuthenticationResponse` method will be called. This method will make a request to pusher with the user credentials and return an array. This array contains Pusher response (socket auth: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php/blob/03d3417748fc70a889c97271e25e282ff1ff0ae3/src/Pusher.php#L586 / Presence Auth: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php/blob/03d3417748fc70a889c97271e25e282ff1ff0ae3/src/Pusher.php#L615) which is a string.

**Short answer**:

Soo.. Pusher require this auth response. Otherwise you won't be able to connect/identify the user (*wss://ws.pusherapp.com*....).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This points me in the right direction, but why might `$result` in `validAuthenticationResponse` be a boolean response from Pusher in different environments?

Comment: `BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis` in your production `.env` file VS `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` locally.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** This is from the version 5.5 docs, not applicable here.

I think the issue maybe with using the '*' wildcard in the channel's name.

I use the following in both local and production:

```
Broadcast::channel("servers.{id}", function (Authenticatable $user, $id) {
    return (int)$user->getAuthIdentifier() === (int)$id;
});
```

Comment: That would be odd since the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#authorizing-channels) says otherwise.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked he noted 5.3 as the version. This is for 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because you did not set the proper `BROADCAST_DRIVER` in your production `.env` file (which is `redis` by default).

```
# before
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis

# after
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```